# Hook to start a Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Is there a simple way to start jobs, only when certain data is available in a DB or a JMS queue, i.e. some kind of conditional job launching / hook, ideally by not using any program that's constantly checking the state of a data source.

Imagine: a preceding job has written some data to a DB, and only when this data is written, the next job will start.

Comment: By simply starting the job from the job that has written the data...

Comment: is there a  possibility without the jobs knowing each other and without starting the 2nd job immediately? see, the 2nd job should start after the first finished AND enough system resources are available on the server

Comment: As stated kick it from the second one when the job finished. Create a `JobExecutionListener` which does that. If you want to loose couple them use an event to indicate something has finished. You could use a Spring Application Event for that and create an ApplicationListener which triggers the next job. Or if you already have some messaging in your application use that mechanism. There is support for Spring Integration in Spring Batch (if you use a new version that is) which basically supports this out-of-the-box.

Comment: Well, you still need some kind of event when "enough system resources are available on the server", maybe launched by the system/db itself. What starts your first batch ? How do you define "when the system has enough resources" ?

Comment: alright, i thought there might be some Spring Batch native mechanism, like a JMS listener, to use. I will implement this using an event framework. fyi: the question "when the system has enough resources" is simply represented as value I'm getting by another team